# Destroy method: Passing params for API gathered data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, destroy

I'm working on an app where users can search for games (data pulled from an API), and add them to a library. I managed to get the adding part working, but I'm having some issues with deleting a game from the user's library.

Here are my create and destroy functions.

```
  def create
    @library_game = Game.new
    @library_game.game_id = params[:game_id]
    @library_game.fetch_data
    @library_game.save!
    current_user.build_library
    current_user.library.games << @library_game
    redirect_to library_path
  end

  def destroy

    current_user.games.destroy(game_id: params[:id])
    redirect_to library_path
  end
```

With the current code, when I try to delete something I get the following error:
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in GamesController#destroy
Game(#70255379902700) expected, got {:game=>"52921"} which is an instance of Hash(#70255376633020)

So it seems to be getting the id but it is expecting the entire game? I have tried editing my params to include just :game or :game_id but I am still getting errors.

Here is the link_to to delete the game.

```
<%= link_to 'Remove from Library', user_game_path(game.id), method: :delete %>
```

Here are my models showing associations.

Game

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :library_games
  has_many :libraries, through: :library_games
  has_many :users, through: :libraries
  serialize :data
  attr_accessor :game_id

  def fetch_data
    game = GiantBomb::Game.detail(game_id)
    self.data = Hash[game.instance_variables.map { |var| [var.to_s[1..-1], game.instance_variable_get(var)] } ]
  end

  def to_giant_bomb_game
    GiantBomb::Game.new(data)
  end
end
```

Library

```
class Library < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :library_games
  has_many :games, through: :library_games
end
```

User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_one :library
  has_many :games, through: :library

  def has_game?(game)
    games.where(id: game.id).exist?
  end

  def build_library
    return if library.present?
    self.library = Library.new
  end
end
```

Library_Game

```
class LibraryGame < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :library
  belongs_to :game
  has_one :user, through: :library
end
```

What am I getting wrong with my destroy method?

Comment: Should it be `current_user.games.where(game_id: params[:id]).destroy`?

Comment: I believe I tried that earlier. I tried it agian to make sure and I get wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) as an error.

Comment: Ah actually, sorry, that would be `destroy_all` because it's getting a result set

Comment: I tried that and get ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in GamesController#destroy, PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column games.game_id does not exist LINE 1: ...raries"."id" WHERE "libraries"."user_id" = $1 AND "games"."g... ^. Also changed it to current_user.library.games.where(game_id: params[:id]).destroy_all but get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding of your domain model,

```
Users (1 to 1)-> Library (1 to n)-> Library Games (1 to 1)-> Games
```

If this understanding is correct, then I see a problem with your create and destroy methods. You should be creating and destroying instances of `LibraryGame`s, and not `Game`s. Below is a rough idea of how you can implement things,

```rb
  def create
    # current_user.build_library # Wouldn't all your users already have libraries?
    @library_game = LibraryGame.new
    @library_game.game_id = params[:game_id]
    @library_game.library = current_user.library
    # @library_game.fetch_data # What does this do? This might not be needed here
    @library_game.save!
    redirect_to library_path
  end

  def destroy
    current_user.library_games.destroy(params[:id])
    redirect_to library_path
  end
```

Comment: I get Validation failed: Game must exist on @library_game.save! using this method. I can already add games to the library with my current create method, so I do not see the need in completely retooling that. I also get method undefined for library_games in the destroy. The fetch_data gets the data from the API (docs here: https://github.com/games-directory/api-giantbomb)

Comment: I am not sure what params you are sending to the `create` request. The reason you should be creating a `LibraryGame` instead of a `Game` in your `create` method is if two users add the same game to their libraries, then you should create a single instance of the Game in your database, but two instances of LibraryGame. Maybe I am mistaken, but from what I understand there seems to be a flaw in your `create` method.

Comment: So should I give my library_game model similar methods to my game model and include attr_accessor: data? LibraryGame.new needs to be an instance of the data I am pulling from the API. Maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but my current create method is working so I wanted to create a destroy method to suit what I already have. Having to copy over a lot of the API data to the LibraryGame model seems redundant.